# Dynamicaly Setting font to a cell of DatagridView

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

In my `winform` am using `DataGgridView`
In some scenario i want to set special font to some column and i achieve that using following code

```
this.grvInvoice.Columns["mat_Name"].DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Verdana", 14);
```

But i want to set certain font and size to some cell only. i try the following code

```
grvRequest.Rows[i].Cells["item"].Style.Font = new Font("Verdana", 14);
```

Bu it doesn't work. Is it possible to `set specific font and size dynamically to a cell of DataGridView`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set a separate style for each cell using this code:

```csh
DataGridViewCell cell=null;
// Get a cell you need here
cell.Style = new DataGridViewCellStyle()
{
        BackColor = Color.White,
        Font = new Font("Tahoma", 8F),
        ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText,
        SelectionBackColor = Color.Red,
        SelectionForeColor = SystemColors.HighlightText
};
```

But if you can't see any results that possibly means that you have set some style on a parent level and that style overrides yours.

For more info check out paragraph **Style Inheritance** of  this article: [Cell Styles in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yef90x0.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps, this is not as it appears.  I had a similar incident.  I created a style

```
private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle styleRed = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
```

and then applied this style to each cell in the row

```
dgvOnForm.Rows[iRow].Cells[i].Style = styleRed;
```

I then wanted to underline one cell, but not the others.  All cells were underlined.  This was not due to inheritence, by a sometimes overlooked fundamental basis for Object Oriented Programming.  The `dgvOnForm.Rows[iRow].Cells[i].Style` was in fact a reference to `styleRed`, and all cells shared the same reference.  Changing any one of them changed them all.  I can't believe I searched so long until it dawned on me. Fix was to create a 'new' style for each cell so they did not share the same reference.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use below code:

```
grvRequest.Rows[i].Cells[0].Style.Add("font-family","Verdana");
grvRequest.Rows[i].Cells[0].Style.Add("font-size", "14");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.its works fine

.Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Trebuchet MS",11, FontStyle.Underline)

Answer (score 0):

Try This 
Me.DataGridView1.Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Tahoma", 11)